# ACF page link shows wrong archive url

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom post type 'products' and use polylang to localize content and rewrite urls. Since I changed the rewrite from 'products' to 'tools', acf shows me the wrong url for the tools archive in a page-link field. 
Where before it showed

```
*/de/products/
```

it now shows

```
*/tools/
```

without the language identifier. I already flushed the wordpress permalink cache without success. All the links generated by wordpress work fine.

This is the custom post type rewrite

```
'rewrite'   => array( 'slug' => 'tools', 'with_front' => false ),
'has_archive' => true,
```

I appreciate your help.